# Prevent TinyMCE from adding spaces within HTML comments

Tags: html, tinymce

For emails I use conditional comments in order to make UI adjustments for Outlook '07+. When saving in TinyMCE it adds a space changing

this

`<!--[if gte mso 9]>`

to this

`<!-- [if gte mso 9]>` (with space before the `[`)

which doesn't get interpreted by Outlook anymore.

Any idea if there is a setting in TinyMCE to prevent this change?

--

Secondary: In case this is easy to add, I'd ideally would like comments to also not be moved to the previous line, but couldn't find a setting for this either.

Example:

```
Some text
<!-- Outlook hack here -->
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<tag>
```

should not become

```
Some text <!-- Outlook hack here --> <!-- [if gte mso 9]>
<tag>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this problem and solved it by adding

allow_conditional_comments: true

Example below taken directly from the documentation: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  allow_conditional_comments: true
});
```

I'm not sure how to best solve the second question.